# Mass of docking system for On-orbit servicing vehicles?

Tags: docking

Could anyone provide an estimate for the mass of on-orbit servicing vehicles such as SMART-OLEV etc 
The mass of the whole vehicle is estimated to be in the range of 1000-1200 kg but what would be the mass of just the docking system

Comment: please link to information have you found so far

Comment: I found a document about the SMART-OLEV and how it connects to the satellites it's repositioning https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11138702.pdf (sidenote: I think its pretty ingenious, especially considering these satellites were not designed with docking capability in mind!) However, this document doesn't really go into the physical specifications of the spacecraft but rather explains how it docks, specifically approach and procedure. Are you asking specifically how much the nozzle attachment hook unit mass?